# ValueError after MinMaxScaler and Transform

Tags: python-3.x, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am experiencing difficulty in this area. I experienced  ValueError in the following: (I have tried solutions online but to no avail)

Here's my original code, which returns Convert String to Float error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,89874,49.99'):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd

training_data_df = pd.read_csv('./data/sales_data_training.csv')
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_training= scaler.fit_transform(training_data_df)
scaled_training_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_training,columns= training_data_df.columns.values)
```

My CSV Data:

```
"critic_rating,is_action,is_exclusive_to_us,is_portable,is_role_playing,is_sequel,is_sports,suitable_for_kids,total_earnings,unit_price"
"3.5,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,132717,59.99"
"4.5,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,83407,49.99"...
'3,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,89874,49.99'
```

I have 9 columns of data across 1000 rows (~9999 data, with first row being the header).

Regards,
Yuki

The full error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/YukiKawaii/PycharmProjects/PandasTest/module2_NN/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    scaled_training= scaler.fit_transform(training_data_df)

  File "C:\Users\YukiKawaii\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 517, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "C:\Users\YukiKawaii\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 308, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\YukiKawaii\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 334, in partial_fit
    estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)

  File "C:\Users\YukiKawaii\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,89874,49.99'
```

Comment: Please clarify **exactly** what your **question** is; remove code unnecessary to your issue - see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `""` and `''` wrapped around each line in the csv file.
By default `pd.read_csv()` splits each line by `,` and thus it cannot convert strings to floats if the `""` and `''` were there.

So the csv file should look as follows.

```
critic_rating,is_action,is_exclusive_to_us,is_portable,is_role_playing,is_sequel,is_sports,suitable_for_kids,total_earnings,unit_price
3.5,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,132717,59.99
4.5,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,83407,49.99
3,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,89874,49.99
```

I just verified by running your code after making the above change.